# How to prevent JAXB escaping a string

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an object, generated by XJC, called `Product`. I want to set `product.currentPrice (a String)` to be `&amp;#x00A3;210` where `&amp;#x00A3;` is the currency symbol (passed in from elsewhere in the system).

Trouble is, JAXB is escaping my ampersand, so it produces `&amp;amp;#x00A3;210` instead. How do I make it not do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506663/can-i-force-jaxb-not-to-convert-into-quot-for-example-when-marshalling-to-x

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, the marshaller implementation of the JAXB usually escapes characters. To change this default behavior you will have to Write a class that implements the `com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler` interface.

set that handler in the Marshaller

```
CharacterEscapeHandler escapeHandler = NoEscapeHandler.theInstance;
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler", escapeHandler);
```

You can have a look at samples provided with JAXB, character escaping sample

Comment: Okay, that's great, but if I do that I am forced to write an implementation that covers how to escape every single character. How do I delegate to the default behaviour if the character is not the one I'm interested in?

Comment: I'm accepting this as the correct answer, because it SHOULD be the correct answer. For anyone else reading this hoping it will help you, this doesn't actually work in JAXB 2.2.1 because of a bug  ( https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=777 )

Comment: Since it seems the source is already escaped, shouldn't it simply be unescaped before passing to JAXB?

Comment: Of the multiple solutions I found online, this was the one that finally fixed the escaping.  Thank you!

Comment: How to set the above properties with xml configuration in spring?

Comment: @Manish Singh, what if I just want it not to escape in the first place? Why do I have to implement a code that could compromise the rest just to disable escaping?

Answer (score 7):

Like rjsang said, there is a bug when using "UTF-8" encoding, which is the default. If you don't care about the case sensitive issues, try using "utf-8" and get your custom escaper to work as it is supposed to do. Also UTF-16 works, anything but "UTF-8": "uTf-8" and so on.

Awful bug in the standard.

Here is the code to do so:

```
marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "utf-8");
```

Comment: This helped me and seems we don't need to use custom escape handlers

Answer (score 2):

Solution for XmlStreamWriter

```
final XMLOutputFactory streamWriterFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
streamWriterFactory.setProperty("escapeCharacters", false);
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508779/809536)

Comment: Also had a comment on the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508779/809536): `"Not documented, so you can't trust this to work in the future"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement this interface: com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler, with your own character escaping, but you want to delegate some behaviour to the traditional escaping, you can use  any of these clases (or write your own code based on them):

- com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.MinimumEscapeHandler
- com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NioEscapeHandler
- com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.DumbEscapeHandler

They come with the JAXB RI Implementation AKA jaxb-impl-2.2.1.jar.

Hope this help to anyone, like it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CDATA section to wrap the value, and then use a JAXB implementation such as [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) that can handle CDATA?

To handle CDATA using MOXy see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html

Answer (score -2):

Depending on what you are exactly looking for you can either :

- disable character escaping
- or use CDATA string which support can be added into JAXB with just a
  bit of configuration

Comment: @fred: you have suggested options, but you have not given example on how to do them.