# Escape output from @Responsebody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-3

Is there a way to escape the XML produced when using @Responsebody.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @Responsebody MyClass asXML(){
    MyClass m = myClassService.get.......;
    return m;
}
```

Now how can I make sure the attributes in m does not contain script tags or similar?

Now I have tested

```
thing.setText("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

This get printed in the XML exactly as it is.

Comment: Have you tested that they are not escaped by the xml mapper by default?

Comment: No I have not. But Is should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's default Xml HttpMessageConverters use JAXB2 for the XML mapping. As you can see from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289036/how-to-prevent-jaxb-escaping-a-string), JAXB escapes XML by default. So you don't need to worry.