# How to write unescaped XML to XMLStreamWriter?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have a number of small XML chunks, that should be embedded in one big XML as child elements. Is there any way to write these chunks to `XMLStreamWriter` without escaping them?

Comment: I don't think you can. It would be *far* too easy to write broken XML that way.

Comment: You could transform your XML with an Xslt identity transform and output the result to a StaxResult based on your XMLStreamWriter...

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sure it would. But let's assume I know what I'm trying to do :).

Comment: I didn't try to imply otherwise ;-) I was just trying to explain a likely reason why this interface is lacking that (kind-of obvious) feature. I think going the path via an identity transformer (just as if writing to a file) is the way to go here

Comment: Thanks for idea. Maybe it makes sense to put it to answer?

Comment: For an answer I'd have to look up the details, I don't think what I wrote here is answer-worthy. But feel free to put it as an answer yourself when you've figured out the nitty-gritty ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below are a couple of options for handling this:

### Option #1 - Use `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`

You could use a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to transform a `StreamSource` representing your XML fragment onto your `StAXResult` which is wrapping your `XMLStreamWriter`.

### Option #2 - Interact Directly with the `OutputStream`

Alternatively you could do something like the following. You can leverage `flush()` to force the `XMLStreamWriter` to output its contents.  Then you'll note that I do `xsw.writeCharacters("")` this forces the start element to end for `bar` before writing the nested XML as a `String`.  The sample code below needs to be flushed out to properly handle encoding issues.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OutputStream stream = System.out;
        
        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(stream);
        
        xsw.writeStartDocument();
        xsw.writeStartElement("foo");
        xsw.writeStartElement("bar");
        
        /* Following line is very important, without it unescaped data 
           will appear inside the <bar> tag. */
        xsw.writeCharacters("");
        xsw.flush();
        
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
        osw.write("<baz>Hello World<baz>");
        osw.flush();
        
        xsw.writeEndElement();
        xsw.writeEndElement();
        xsw.writeEndDocument();
        xsw.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: With the second approach you'd have to be careful to use the exact same encoding in the `OutputStreamWriter` than the output factory is configured to. Even defaulting to UTF-8 would be more likely to work than just using the platform default encoding (as you currently do).

Comment: I didn't get option #1 to work. The transform inserts a `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the beginning of the fragment and closes of the original tags at the end(in your example the `foo` and `bar` elements would be closed after the transformer has run. Try it to see what I mean.

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of option 1?

Answer (score 2):

woodstox has a stax implementation and their [XMLStreamWriter2](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/3.2.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/stax2/XMLStreamWriter2.html) class has a writeRaw() call. We have the same need and this gave us a very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
final XMLOutputFactory streamWriterFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
streamWriterFactory.setProperty("escapeCharacters", false);
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508779/809536)

Comment: It simplest solution! Thank you.

Comment: Xerces specific.