# How do i reuse parts of XML document with Woodstox writeRaw WITH indentation?

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

I am writing a pretty large document, with quite a few repeating elements. I don't want to recreate those elements every time, but store them in memory and print them.

I have found [other SO threads on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998460/how-to-write-unescaped-xml-to-xmlstreamwriter), where the answer is to use Woodstox/Stax2 and the writeRaw()-function.

This works fine for me, but i would also like the resulting stream to be pretty printed.

The [SO threads discussing that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616383/xmlstreamwriter-indentation) all are about using the IndentingXMLStreamWriter - however, there is no such class for WoodStox, so there is no writeRaw-method i can use.

I would like to avoid reading in the entire string in memory, and i have not been able to get it to work.

Pointers appreciated!

Comment: @vtd-xml-author if there is a sample of simple one or two-liner with indentation, maybe you can add a link?

Comment: I looked at VTD, but didn't use it. 1. seemed more complex to use 2. not updated since 2015 3. site was a mess 4. no examples matched my usecase